# htaccess redirect one folder to another on same domain if request_uri condition false

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to redirect the visitors if they visit the old not working URL `example.com/english/*` to `example.com/german/*` but not when they're visiting `example.com/`

This code in .htaccess is not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/german/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^/english/(.*)$ /german/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

I searched throrough the apache docs and google but nothing does the same.
Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^english/(.*)$ /german/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

`RewriteRule` doesn't match leading slash in .htaccess.

Comment: But is it working when user visits `/` or `/german/`? The two `RewriteCond`s are not needed?

Comment: Tested with `RewriteCond`, it works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, but not in Palemoon: `The page isn't redirecting properly. Pale Moon has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

Comment: Cleared everything: cache, cookies, etc. and browser closed, restarted, but again I got this error...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test with `Palemoon` since I have never heard about it before. This rule is pretty simple and it has nothing to do with any browser. I tested with Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE and it worked fine on all of them.

Comment: OK. But what is with `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Not getting that. Did you have to modify my suggested rule?

Comment: Please see 1. comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42354/discussion-between-anubhava-and-tib)